# insertar 2 elementos a la vez a una lista

Tags: python, lista, numpy

Necesito añadir 2 elementos a mi lista de tipo numérica, como coordenadas de planos en [x, y] de la siguiente forma:

```
[[100, 500], [20, -200], [84, 55], [400, 0]]
```

Todo bien mientras no hago casting

```
puntos_manuales = list()
for i in range(4):
    print('Insterte el par de numeros ', i+1 )
    puntos_manuales.append(int(input([])))

pts_robot = np.array(puntos_manuales, dtype="float32")
```

básicamente es eso pero no encuentro la solución de una forma optima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que lees con `input()` es una cadena. Si quieres que el usuario pueda meter dos datos en un solo input, debes decidir cómo han de estar separados, y entonces puedes usar `entrada.split(separador)` para obtener una lista con cada elemento. Cada elemento seguirá siendo una cadena, por lo que debes convertirlos individualmente a `int` o `float` o lo que necesites, por ejemplo con una *list comprehension*.

Supongamos que el separador es un espacio. En ese caso sería así:

```
puntos_manuales = list()
for i in range(4):
    linea = input("Inserte el par de números {}, separados por espacios: ".format(i+1))
    datos = [int(dato) for dato in linea.split()]
    puntos_manuales.append(datos)

pts_robot = np.array(puntos_manuales, dtype="float32")
```

Comment: si era exactamente lo q buscaba!! .. llevaba tiempo buscando sobre el trabajo con listas e introduciendo los datos de diferentes formas y el problema era ese... Gracias @abulafia